# Reading a cell value using java or google script

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, cell

I need a help reading cell value using either java or google script. The cell I am trying to read has a formula. When my script reads the data I get #DIV\0! error.

here is my simple script:

```
function readData(){
  var Keys = "1Vp_fjFVFXHDjJRXl7C6mNzCK66jVB1I1BjieaZK6P";
  var SheetName = "AAL";
  var WR;

  SS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(Keys);
  Sheet = SS.getSheetByName(SheetName);
  Range = Sheet.getDataRange(); 
  Data = Range.getValues();

  WR = Data[30][15];
}
```

Any help will be appriciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing [30][15], use this code to limit the range to one cell.

If that doesn't work, maybe your cell actually contains this DIV/0 value?

```
function readData(){
  var Keys = "1Vp_fjFVFXHDjJRXl7C6mNzCK66jVB1I1BjieaZK6P";
  var SheetName = "AAL";
  var WR;

  SS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(Keys);
  Sheet = SS.getSheetByName(SheetName);
  Range = Sheet.getRange(30, 15); //changed here 
  Data = Range.getValue(); //and here

  WR = Data; //and here
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I am still getting the same error. If there is a "typed" value, that works fine, but the result from a formula, errors. Is there an easy way to convert the calculated value to an absolate value?